# better way to match text and replace

Tags: python, replace, match, performance

Consider this, I have File1:

```
SNP_ID  GENE_ID # Header not present in original file
rs1 TRIML1,TRIML2
rs2 D4S234E
rs4 ACCN5,CTSO
rs5 ODZ3
rs6 TRIML1
```

and File2:

```
SNP1_ID SNP2_ID DRUG # Header not present in original file
rs1 rs2 xyz
rs1 rs8 abc
rs2 rs4 xyz
rs2 rs5 abc1
rs5 rs7 abc2
rs6 rs5 xyz1
```

I want to match SNP IDs in file2 to file1 and replace with the corresponding Gene IDs and also have the drug name in the output. The output should look like:

```
GENE1_ID    GENE2_ID    SNP1_ID SNP2_ID Drug
TRIML1  D4S234E rs1 rs2 xyz
TRIML2  D4S234E rs1 rs2 xyz
TRIML1  rs8 rs1 rs8 abc
TRIML2  rs8 rs1 rs8 abc
D4S234E ACCN5   rs2 rs4 xyz
D4S234E CTSO    rs2 rs4 xyz
D4S234E ODZ3    rs2 rs5 abc1
ODZ3    rs7 rs5 rs7 abc2
TRIML1  ODZ3    rs6 rs5 xyz1
```

I wrote the following code to do the match and replacement, but I can't figure out to get the last three columns in the output. Also, this takes quite a time when I have to do this on big files. Inputs on doing it efficiently??

```
 snp_gene_dict = {}
 with open('File1') as f1:
     for line in f1:
         snp_key = line.split()[0]
         vals = line.split()[1]
         gene_val = vals.split(',')
         snp_gene_dict[snp_key] = gene_val

 col0 = []
 col1 = []
 snp_first_col = []
 snp_second_col = []
 with open('File2') as f2:
     for line in f2:
         snp0, snp1 = line.split()
             col0.append(snp0)
             col1.append(snp1)
     for i in range(len(col0)):
          if col0[i] in snp_gene_dict.keys():
              snp_first_col.append(snp_gene_dict[col0[i]])
          else:
              snp_first_col.append([col0[i]])
     for i in range(len(col1)):
          if col1[i] in snp_gene_dict.keys():
              snp_second_col.append(snp_gene_dict[col1[i]])
          else:
              snp_second_col.append([col1[i]])

 with open('output-gene-gene', 'w') as out:
     for i,j in map(None,snp_first_col,snp_second_col): 
         if len(i) ==  1 and len(j) == 1:
             out.write ('{a}\t{b} \n'.format(a = '\t'.join(i), b = '\t'.join(j)))
         elif len(i) > 1 and len(j) == 1:
             for item in i:
                 out.write ('{a}\t{b} \n'.format(a = item, b = '\t'.join(j)))
         elif len(j) > 1 and len(i) == 1:
             for item in j:
                 out.write ('{a}\t{b} \n'.format(a = '\t'.join(i), b= item))
         elif len(i) > 1 and len(j) > 1:
             for elem1 in i:
                 for elem2 in j:
                     out.write('{a}\t{b} \n'.format(a = elem1, b = elem2))
```

Comment: @ Nix I don't know sqlite, just a beginner!

Comment: Just wanted to make sure you were free to use any tools that were available, I was thinking you could read the first files into a sqlite database, and then query on it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it using SQLITE, concept is pretty simple.  Just insert FILE1 into the database and then read from it.

```
import logging
INSERT_SPN_STATEMENT = 'INSERT INTO spn_table (spn_id, gene_id) VALUES (?, ?)'
SELECT_SPN_BY_ID_STATEMENT='SELECT ID FROM spn_table WHERE spn_id=? and GENE_ID=?'
def dump_file_to_db(File1, connection):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    for l in File1:
        #line looks like:  rs1 TRIML1,TRIML2, split will split on spaces and since we have 2 we can save it in 2 vars
        SPN_ID, GENE_ID = l.split()
        for g in GENE_ID.split(','):#now for each gene (comma separated) insert into the spn_table
            cursor.execute(SELECT_SPN_BY_ID_STATEMENT , (SPN_ID, g))
            if cursor.fetchone(): continue # record exists
            cursor.execute(INSERT_SPN_STATEMENT , (SPN_ID, g))
    connection.commit()

SELECT_SPN_STATEMENT = 'SELECT ID, spn_id, gene_id FROM spn_table WHERE spn_id=?'
def read_file(File2, connection):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    for l in File2:
        spn1, spn2, drug = l.split()
        #get spn1 from database
        cursor.execute(SELECT_SPN_STATEMENT , (spn1,))
        _id, spn1_id, gene_id = cursor.fetchone()
        cursor.execute(SELECT_SPN_STATEMENT , (spn2,))
        _id, spn2_id, gene_id = cursor.fetchone()
        logging.info("%s %s %s %s", spn1_id, spn2_id, gene_id, drug)


def initialize_db():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db');c = conn.cursor()
    # Create table
    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS spn_table
             (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, spn_id text, gene_id text)''')
    return conn

import sqlite3
connection = initialize_db()
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.info("Started")
with open('File1.txt') as File1:
    dump_file_to_db(File1, connection)
with open('File2.txt') as File2:
    read_file(File2, connection)
logging.info("Done")
```